Remove surounding spaces in "plus" symbol CharisSIL font
In type1 CharisSil font text mode + symbol has a big bounding box width. I'm using luatex with TL2024 (in texlive 2019  it is the same).
Compiling without \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} plus symbol looks normal (without surrounding additional spaces).
UPDATE: this problem exists with open type fonts as well. For example with \usepackage{lmodern} plus symbol in text mode is begger too then minus but kerning is ok.
I've tried to fix adding negative kerns around the + and it works ok in the text but in tabular I got incorrect formatting.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[type1]{CharisSIL}

\directlua{
    local utfchar = unicode.utf8.char
    local KERN = node.id("kern")
    local GLYPH = node.id("glyph")
    local HLIST = node.id("hlist") 
    local VLIST = node.id("vlist")
    function string.starts(String,Start)
       return string.sub(String,1,string.len(Start))==Start
    end
    local function new_kern(subtype,kern)
        local n = node.new(KERN)
        n.subtype = subtype or 0
        n.kern = kern or 0
        return n
    end
    function fixCharisSilPlus(h,parent)
        for n in node.traverse(h) do
            local id = n.id
            if n.id == GLYPH and utfchar(n.char) == '+' then
                local f = font.getfont(n.font)
                if string.starts(f.name, 'charssil') then
                    plus_kern_factor = n.width/7
                    local kern_pre = new_kern(1, -plus_kern_factor) 
                    h = node.insert_before(h, n, kern_pre)
                    if n.next and n.next.id == GLYPH then
                      local kern_post = new_kern(1, -plus_kern_factor) 
                      node.insert_after(h, n, kern_post)
                    end
                end
            end
            if id == HLIST or id == VLIST then 
                if node.length(n.head) > 1 then
                  fixCharisSilPlus(n.head, n)
                end  
            end
        end 
        return h
    end
}
\fboxsep=0pt
\begin{document}
\par text: x+x-x; programming in C++

tabular:\par
\begin{tabular}{r|}
0-1\\
0+1
\end{tabular}
\vspace{10pt}

\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback("pre_linebreak_filter",fixCharisSilPlus,"fixCharisSilPlus")}
\par text: x+x-x; programming in C++

tabular:\par
\begin{tabular}{r|}
0-1\\
0+1
\end{tabular}
\end{document}

Can I fix some how via LUATEX bounding box for + symbol in Type1 fonts. Or I'll need to create some virtual font for it?
UPDATE: If there are multiple + it looks very ugly (see C++).
I'm looking for a global solution how to fix Churissil font issue for the journal which typesets in DVI->PS->PDF workflow.

Use a typographical correct minus sign (U+2212) at least.

don't load fontenc with lualatex.

are you trying to fix this for something you're submitting to the journal? or are you trying to fix it for submissions by other people? this matters because I think the best solution for the first is the more traditional macro-based approach: C++ is a proper name and rather odd, just as e.g. TeX is, so I'd be inclined to handle it in the same way. but that may not scale if you have a flow of submissions from authors and need to correct their submissions. at least, it can scale and I think that's still likely the way to go, but it is rather more complicated in that case. but why type1?

@cfr, yes I am doing a typesetting job. And was using this lua script for some journals with this font for a long time. Just now I faced an issue with the + inside right  aligned tabular cell.

well, the right solution, in my opinion, would be to treat C++ as a logo, similar to TeX etc. and use a macro.

This isn't the answer you want, but, IMHO, it is the correct answer ;). As Jasper Habicht indicated, the inconsistent output is not due to a problem with the plus sign, but to your use of a hyphen in place of a minus sign.
In addition, you shouldn't use fontenc with a Unicode engine unless you have some very special reason and really know what you're doing. This is most obviously not the case where the postscript type1 font is simply converted from truetype or opentype format, which are provided and supported by the same LaTeX package, as in the case of CharisSIL.
If you correct these two things, I can see no inconsistency requiring manual tweaking of kerns etc. Moreover, IMHO, the spacing around the operators looks correct.

In addition, your PDF will use the correct Unicode characters, which is necessary for search, copy-paste and screen-readers1.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CharisSIL}

\fboxsep=0pt
\begin{document}

\par text: x+x\textminus x


tabular:\par
\begin{tabular}{r|}
0\textminus 1\\
0+1
\end{tabular}
\end{document}

1Currently the third point is less than persuasive, given that much more is required if the PDF is to make sense to screen-reading software. Depending on your field, this may or may not continue to hold true. But the first two points don't depend on this further one.

I updated original question with several ++ example.  I agree, that \texminus looks better but the problem is with big spaces around +.  Luatex has ability to create virtual font so I'm waiting maybe somebody already did something similar before and will give an example how  to edit virtual font. I see it uses charssil-tlf-t1.vf

@Linuxss that's a traditional virtual font intended for use with e.g. pdfTeX. I haven't checked but, given the package author, I assume it was created with autoinst. why do you want to use type1 fonts with a unicode engine?

Typesetting process is build on dviluatex. And accessible pdf tags are managed there via \specials.

@Linuxss that doesn't explain why you want to use a non-unicode encoding with a unicode engine.
